# How to get text embedded in the div class using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the text Life of Pi from the html code below. I have tried many different variations of find but none of them seem to find the right div or be able to extract the text i want from the html code.

I have tried:

```
movie_name = browser.find_element_by_class_name("_14Rip")
movie = movie_name.get_attribute('text')

movie_name = browser.find_element('_14Rip').getText()
```

Neither of these worked. Also .getText threw an error concerning the 'WebElement' object. I was wondering how i could extract this text while still using python and selenium?

```html
<div id="reactApp"><div data-reactroot=""><!-- react-empty: 2 --><!-- react-empty: 3 --><div class="nr-medium-page main-page-container"><span><div class="_1gHrf"></div><nav class="_2ng5l"><div class="_1nd6r"><span class="_3Jg52 _2Dfpe"><a href="/content/movies/home"><span class="_2RaqC "></span></a></span><span><span class="_3Jg52 _2Dfpe"><span class="_1sHRG"><a href="/content/movies/movieslist">Movies</a></span></span><div class="_34DjI" style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; transform: translateY(-100%); z-index: 1; left: 116.875px;"><div class="_3kwAy nr-m-30"><div class="_2h_ha"><a href="/content/movies/movieslist">VIEW ALL MOVIES</a></div><div><div class="_223L6"></div></div></div></div></span><span><span class="_3Jg52 _2Dfpe"><span class="_1sHRG"><a href="/content/movies/tvlist">TV</a></span></span><div class="_34DjI" style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; transform: translateY(-100%); z-index: 1; left: 180.974px;"><div class="_3kwAy nr-m-30"><div class="_2h_ha"><a href="/content/movies/tvlist">VIEW ALL TV</a></div><div><div class="_223L6"></div></div></div></div></span><span><span class="_3Jg52 _2Dfpe"><span class="_1sHRG"><a href="/content/movies/myvudu">My Vudu</a></span></span><div class="_34DjI" style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; transform: translateY(-100%); z-index: 1; left: 252.224px;"><div class="ZvRao"><a href="/content/movies/mymovies">My Movies</a><a href="/content/movies/mytv">My TV</a><a href="/content/movies/mywishlist">My Wishlist</a><a href="/content/movies/mypreorders">My Pre-orders</a><a href="/content/movies/myoffers">My Offers</a></div></div></span><span><span class="_3Jg52 _2Dfpe"><span class="_1sHRG"><a href="/content/movies/free">Free</a></span></span><div class="_34DjI" style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; transform: translateY(-100%); z-index: 1; left: 349.104px;"><div class="_3kwAy nr-m-30"><div class="_2h_ha"><a href="/content/movies/free">VIEW ALL FREE MOVIES &amp; TV</a></div><div><div class="_223L6"></div></div></div></div></span><span class="_3Jg52 _2Dfpe _3uvRn"><span class="kzzv5"><span class="_1sHRG"><span class="_72isQ"></span></span></span></span><span><span class="_3Jg52 _2Dfpe _3uvRn _28Da_ _18Vtj"><span class="_1sHRG"><span><div><div class="_3yhAh"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div><div class="_3p4_i"><!-- react-text: 71 -->Hi, Zachary!<!-- /react-text --></div></div></span></span></span><div class="_34DjI" style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; transform: translateY(-100%); z-index: 1; left: 1035px;"><div class="ZvRao"><a href="https://www.vudu.com/content/AccountManage.html#accountInfo">Account Settings</a><a href="javascript:void(0);">Payment Info</a><a href="https://www.vudu.com/content/AccountManage.html#balanceHistory">Balance &amp; History</a><a href="https://www.vudu.com/content/MyDevices.html">Manage Devices</a><a href="http://support.vudu.com/?supportPage=home">Support</a><a href="javascript:void(0);">Log Out</a></div></div></span><span><span class="_3Jg52 _2Dfpe _3uvRn _28Da_ _18Vtj"><span class="_1sHRG"><span>Redeem</span></span></span><div class="_34DjI _231pT" style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; transform: translateY(-100%); z-index: 1; left: 509.88px;"><div class="ZvRao"><a href="https://www.vudu.com/content/redeem.html">Digital Copy</a><a href="https://www.vudu.com/vuducodes">Vudu Code</a></div></div></span></div></nav></span><div class="nr-page-body"><div><div class="_2vzt3"></div><div class="_1_90a"><div class="_36fun"><div class="container nr-width-100 nr-mt-20 nr-p-0"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="_11CIH nr-mr-20"><button class="_3wvTg _1PvrS _2WUnj _2Jfzj"><span class="_2O7IK"><span class="_6D7oD">Filters</span><span class="_29qeU"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></span></span></button></div></div></div></div><div class="page-section nr-mt-10 nr-pt-20 sb-t2"></div><div class="_3oON0"><div class="_1RtHb"><div class="ki1tU" style="width: calc(34% - 0px);">Recently Purchased</div><div style="width: calc(34% - 0px);">A - Z</div><div style="width: calc(34% - 0px);">Release Date</div></div></div><!-- react-empty: 150 --></div></div><div class="mLd3t"><div class="_2qGVw "><span>My Movies</span><span><!-- react-text: 155 -->&nbsp;(<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 156 -->124<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 157 -->)<!-- /react-text --></span></div><div><div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 253.333px; z-index: 2;"><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%;"><div class="nr-pt-40" style="max-height: 1156px; overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%; height: 324.667px; padding-left: calc(50% - 314px);"><div style="position: relative; min-height: 7347px; width: 628px;"><div class="contentPosterWrapper" style="width: 142px; height: 237px; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 2;"><div class="_1-zjZ"><a href="/content/movies/details/The-Social-Network/182239"><div class="_3YJBG  content-poster"><div class="_1witT"><span class="_2KzEp"><div class="_1LPN- _3YCP4"><img src="https://images2.vudu.com/poster2/182239-142" alt="The Social Network"></div></span></div><div class="_20xkP"></div></div></a></div></div><div class="contentPosterWrapper" style="width: 142px; height: 237px; left: 162px; top: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 2;"><div class="_1-zjZ"><a href="/content/movies/details/Snatch/21789"><div class="_3YJBG  content-poster"><div class="_1witT"><span class="_2KzEp"><div class="_1LPN- _3YCP4"><img src="https://images2.vudu.com/poster2/21789-142" alt="Snatch"></div></span></div><div class="_20xkP"></div></div></a></div></div><div class="contentPosterWrapper" style="width: 142px; height: 237px; left: 324px; top: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 2;"><div class="_1-zjZ"><a href="/content/movies/details/Life-of-Pi/391851"><div class="_3YJBG dkbEJ content-poster"><div class="_1witT"><span class="_2KzEp"><div class="_1LPN- _3YCP4"><img src="https://images2.vudu.com/poster2/391851-142" alt="Life of Pi"></div></span></div><div class="_20xkP dkbEJ"><div class="_1KXuV"><div class="_2QBtI _1kJwC"><div class="_1yDEt _33qR9 _4mlb1 _25_Pp"><div class="_14Rip"><!-- react-text: 464 -->Life of Pi<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 465 --> <!-- /react-text --></div></div><div class="_33qR9 "><span class="_2kH_h">2012</span><span class="_2kH_h"><span class="_2W2ik ">PG</span></span><span class="_2kH_h"><span class="_35HrQ BE5VD"></span></span><span class="_2kH_h"><span class="Xmp5C gLWM-"></span></span></div>
```

If I try just .text i get this error also:

```
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
```

Comment: Can you share the URL so we can test?

Comment: The Url is part of a website that you need login info for, is there a better way so you can test?

Comment: I added more html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First try:**

`.get_attribute('text')` is not valid and `Element.text` only for visible text, try using attribute `'textContent'`

```
movie_name = browser.find_element_by_class_name("_14Rip")
movie = movie_name.get_attribute('textContent')
```

**Second Try:**

From your HTML above there is only one class `_14Rip` but it has 3 movies, could it be the element only appended when it hovered? but let try alternative method by extracting movie title by `alt` image and adding `WebDriverWait`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

.....
.....
# put this after login or clicking login button
# wait max 30 second
WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class="_2KzEp"] img")))
movie_names = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class="_2KzEp"] img")
for name in movie_names:
    print(name.get_attribute('alt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [attribute=value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) CSS selector combined with element selector. This assumes you want the first div element matching that class name. You would use find_elements if more than one and you needed a later one. Then you would index into that collection to return the appropriate match. Sharing more HTML/URL would help refine this.

```
print(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='_14Rip']").text)
```

Comment: Trying this causes a selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._14Rip"}

Comment: Try div[class='_14Rip'] and are you leaving enough time on page load and do you have to scroll element into view?

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same result and i have it so there is a 10 second delay before it tries to find that element and you dont have to scroll to see it

Comment: Then there is something we are missing. Is it in a parent iframe/frame? Does anything need to be clicked to expose the element?

Comment: All i did to find the name was right click on the image and click inspect which helped me find the path.

Comment: Not ideal but browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[alt]")[2]).get_attribute("alt")     or try with 3 instead of 2 as not sure of python indexing.

Comment: Did you try my comment above where I suggested using the alt attribute?

Comment: It gives this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'                             I updated the post with an answer that worked, i had to use xpath though

Comment: Did you use the index into the list of 2?

Answer (score 0):

`getText()` is a Java method. You are looking for `text` member. You also need to tell the driver *how* to find it, `by_class_name` in your case

```
movie_name = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_14Rip').text
```

You can also locate using `By` class

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME, '_14Rip'))
```

Comment: Sorry i was editing, i forgot to add that when i try .text i also get an error saying i have an invalid argument, that value must be a string. I was wondering if because of where the text was the .text couldn't find it correctly?

Comment: @ZacharyRW Updated my answer.

Comment: When i tried     movie_name = browser.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME, '_14Rip')).text    it gave me     NameError: name 'By' is not defined. I looked it up and by is part of common selenium so im wondering why this wasnt defined

Comment: @ZacharyRW Sorry, I forgot to tell you need to import it. Added to the answer.

Comment: No problem!! It fixed that error but now it says     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string     I read it could be a problem with the parameters?

Comment: @ZacharyRW Maybe, delete `'_14Rip'` and retype it manually (instead of copy-paste).

Comment: @ZacharyRW What version of selenium are you using? maybe you need to update it.

Comment: I have the latest, 3.141.0

Comment: @ZacharyRW What about your Chrome version?

Comment: Also using the latest version of chrome

Answer (score 0):

I used a large part of the answer that user ewwink proposed. Instead of going for the String name that i was trying to get, i had to use the one attached to an image.

I used .find_elements_by_xpath because it got me right to the image that had the text attribute i wanted. The css selector recommended also threw errors saying it could not find the element. It seemed to have a problem with span. Thanks again to everyone who helped me find a solution!

```
# Used to get the movie names from the webpage
# If the page loads as you scroll down you would need to loop through this code

movie_list = []

movie_names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="reactApp"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/a/div/div[1]/span/div/img')

for name in movie_names:
        # Add movie name to list
        movie = name.get_attribute('alt')
        movie_list.append(movie)
```